# Get the string of a Windows Message in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-messages

I see that I can send strings in Windows Messages.
But how do I read them from a processed Windows Message?

Comment: Erm, *what* message?  And what's the difference with an un-processed messsage?

Comment: I assume Windows Messages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632590%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` or (`Marshal.PtrToStringUni()` / `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto()`)

Comment: which windows messages would these methods help with?